# Devise 'current_user' not working properly in controller?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am probably missing something extreamly obvious, but I can't figure this our for the life of me...

I am trying to preform a simple `before_filter` check in my `Orders_Controller`, to see if the Devise `current_user.vendor_id == params[:vendor_id]`. It returns false every time, redirecting my to the `root_path`, as I have it set up in my `orders_controller`...

```
before_filter :check_vendor
.
.
.
private

def check_vendor
 unless current_user.vendor_id == params[:vendor_id]
  redirect_to root_path, :flash => { error: "Sorry, but you don't have sufficient privlidges to view that page" }
 end
end
```

The strangest thing is when I login with a user, and navigate to

```
http://localhost:3000/vendors/3/orders/
```

and have this code in my index:

```
<%= current_user.vendor_id %> <%= params[:vendor_id] %>
```

It prints out on in the `orders#index` view:

```
3 3
```

Which should mean that when I use the same logic in the controller, it see's that both values are '3' (or whatever the `current_user.vendor_id` and `params[:vendor_id]` is)

Any help would be greatly appreciated :) Sorry if it is an obvious answer, I am pretty new at Rails still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're sending de param[:vendor_id] in the first request to the controller?

I would add `gem 'debugger'` to my gemfile, run `bundle install`, and put `debugger` just above the comparisson in the before_filter.

Then check params and current user values.

Comment: Ah! I have never used `debugger` before. What an awesome tool! Okay, I think I have narrowed down my problem -- for some reason it seems as if my `params[:vendor_id]` value isn't an integer? Screenshot -> http://cl.ly/IwSb. If it is pulling that value from the URL though, how would it be thinking that it is not an integer?

Comment: Okay, it is now working properly if I add `.to_i` to the `params[:vendor_id]`, but that is really odd that the URL :id wouldn't be an integer, isn't it?

Comment: Parameters are always strings. When passing directly as attributes to models, rails (probably ActiveModel or ActiveRecord) do some conversion on your behalf based on your schema (so that an id is an integer in the db, so it nows to call to_i on it, etc). Since you are using the raw parameters here, you need to do the conversion. There are some occasions where you don't want your ids to be integers, like when using FriendlyId or something similar.

Comment: That's right. It's perfectly acceptable that you call to_i. =)

Comment: By the way.. if the :id is not passed in the URL, don't worry because to_i will convert it to 0, and that won't match any vendor_id.

Comment: Ahh nice! Good to know. Thanks for all of your help!